# Deserialization of an array always gives an array of nulls

Tags: c#, arrays, deserialization, iserializable

I have a custom abstract base class with sub classes that I've made serializable/deseriablizeable with ISerializable. When I do serialization/deserialization of single instances of this class' sub classes, everything works fine. However, when I do an array of them I always end up with an array of nulls on deserialization. Serialization is done with BinaryFormatter.

The items are contained within a:

```
public ObservableCollection<Trade> Trades { get; private set; }
```

On serialization this is done in GetObjectData on the SerializationInfo parameter:

```
Trade[] trades = (Trade[])Trades.ToArray<Trade>();
            info.AddValue("trades", trades);
```

And on deserialization this is done in the serialization constructor also on the SerializationInfo parameter:

```
Trade[] trades = (Trade[])info.GetValue("trades", typeof(Trade[]));

            foreach (Trade t in trades)
            {
                Trades.Add(t);
            }
```

Deserialization always gives me an array of nulls and as I mentioned earlier, a single item serializes and deseriaizes just fine with this code:

Serialization (GetObjectData method):

```
info.AddValue("trade", Trades.First<Trade>());
```

Deserialization (Serialization Constructor):

```
Trade t = (Trade)info.GetValue("trade", typeof(Trade));
            Trades.Add(t);
```

Is this a common problem? I seem to find no occurrences of anyone else running in to it at least. Hopefully there is a solution :) and if I need to supply you with more information/code just tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what is info variable? What is the format of serialization? Xml or binary?

Comment: it's the SerializationInfo that I use in the GetObjectData and the Serialization-constructor, sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126155/c-array-xml-serialization Any help?

Comment: What is line for Trade[] trades = (Trade[])Trades.ToArray<Trade>();? Why don't you just say var trades = Trades.ToArray(); (Linq Extension)

Comment: Polity: I'm doing binary serialization so I don't think I have such tags available.

Comment: The_Smallest: For some reason I thought I had to give the types everywhere :) works without though. I'm going to test if it makes any difference in the result. EDIT: I made the Trade[] syntax change, although obviously no changes in the results.

Comment: Please show your Trade class (I think you have error there)

Comment: I've run into this a couple of times now, its a right pain :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Array deserializes first. Then all inner deserialization is done. So when you try to access items, they are null.

And idea to use `[OnDeserialized]` Attribute on some method, that builds up all other properies. And here is example:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestClass : ISerializable
{
    private Trade[] _innerList;
    public ObservableCollection<Trade> List { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    { }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void SetValuesOnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.List = new ObservableCollection<Trade>(_innerList);
        this._innerList = null;
    }

    protected TestClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var value = info.GetValue("inner", typeof(Trade[]));
        this._innerList = (Trade[])value;
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("inner", this.List.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try and look into it a bit more and supply some more code in my question. I'm actually doing serialization on a class that contains this array of serializable objects. One alternative is to serialize the whole array with different names in SerializationInfo. "trade1" and so on.

Comment: Updated answer, now this should help)

Comment: Testing it out now, give me a second. You're too fast :) I didn't even get to finish my new test project :D

Comment: The Severe Russian programmer knows all the answers :) Thanks again!

Comment: @vesz I just like your questions) You ask it just on time: 2 o'clock in the morning)

Comment: The best time to ask it seems :)